# Values Stops Somewhere that it shouldn't

Tags: matlab

I have 365 (days) input for my graphic but in somewhere it is stop making graphics
It is my graphic result:
[My Graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Ya8.png)

Here, original graphic that I should get :
[Original Graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mks7E.png)

Here my whole code:

```
days = 1:365;
%Formulas of the Equation of Time
earth_tilt = -7.655*sin(2*pi*days/365)
elliptical_orbit = 9.873*sin(4*pi*days/365+3.588)
time_variation = earth_tilt + elliptical_orbit
plot(days,earth_tilt,'g--')
hold on
plot(days,elliptical_orbit,'r-.')
plot(days,time_variation,'black')
ax = gca;
ax.XAxisLocation = 'origin';
ax.XAxis.TickLabels = {'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'}';
ax.XAxis.Limits = [0 500];
title('Time Variation')
xlabel('Day of The Year','FontWeight','bold')
ylabel('Minutes','FontWeight','bold')
legend({'Earth Elliptic Orbit','Tilt of Earth Axis','Orbit+Tilt'},'FontSize',14)
% Location information of legend
set(legend, 'Location', 'NorthWest')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting the label *text* but not the label *position*, letting MATLAB chose where it wants them to be. Specifically, your ticks are at:

```
ax.XAxis.TickValues

ans =

     0    50   100   150   200   250   300   350   400   450   500
```

Which do not correspond to the labels you are inputting. Change these locations:

```
days = 1:365;
%Formulas of the Equation of Time
earth_tilt = -7.655*sin(2*pi*days/365)
elliptical_orbit = 9.873*sin(4*pi*days/365+3.588)
time_variation = earth_tilt + elliptical_orbit
plot(days,earth_tilt,'g--')
hold on
plot(days,elliptical_orbit,'r-.')
plot(days,time_variation,'black')
ax = gca;
ax.XAxisLocation = 'origin';
ax.XAxis.TickLabels = {'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'}';
ax.XAxis.Limits = [0 500];

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
ax.XAxis.TickValues=[0:30:360]; % yeah its not 100% right, change it to @Brice's answer data.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

title('Time Variation')
xlabel('Day of The Year','FontWeight','bold')
ylabel('Minutes','FontWeight','bold')
legend({'Earth Elliptic Orbit','Tilt of Earth Axis','Orbit+Tilt'},'FontSize',14)
% Location information of legend
set(legend, 'Location', 'NorthWest')
```

[image]

You need to change the TickValues to correct days (I assumed every month has 20 days) and possibly the Limits of `Xaxis`, to avoid the unnecessary empty space after the data, I leave that to the reader, as I assume the asker had 500 for some reason.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin purely for visualization purposes, it does not make my answer wrong. Modified to show its not the problem

Comment: This will still not result in the final picture in the question, as it leaves white space

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin yes XD I changed it **because** you said I changed the range, to show that changing the range was **not** the solution, but just an improvement on visualization. Now my `xlimit` does not differ from the asker and the labels are in the correct location.

Answer (score 7):

```
ax.XAxis.TickLabels = {'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'}';
```

The label names are changed, but there is no mention to where these lables should appear. By default, they will be spread evenly over the 500 days of the graph (`ax.XAxis.Limits = [0 500];`)

Set the tick positions correctly

```
ax.XAxis.Tick=cumsum([31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31])-30;
```

Comment: You are less lazy that I am defining the Ticks :P